# Keyboard exits fullscreen mode on older Android versions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to use fullscreen in my app, but I noticed that on devices with android 8.1 (API 27), when the user opens a keyboard the app exits fullscreen mode and doesn't comeback unless the ui is rebuild, does anyone have a solution?

I also tested on Android 7.1 (API 25) and the problem is easier to deal with, the only thing that doesn't come back to fullscreen is the top bar, but still, the code below only works flawless on new androids (API 28 +)

Code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Flexible(flex: 1, child: Text('Fullscreen test')),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: TextEditingController(),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox())
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Exemple on Android 8.1]

Answer (score 0):

You should call this in `initState`. Working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
void initState() {
 // TODO: implement initState
 super.initState();
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: SafeArea(
       child: Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       Flexible(flex: 1, child: Text('Fullscreen test')),
       Flexible(
         flex: 1,
         child: TextFormField(
           controller: TextEditingController(),
         ),
       ),
       Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox())
     ],
   )),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But the problem is when you open the keyboard, it overrides the overlay settings :/ so placing the settings in initState doesn't fix